# Gulp iconfont css not generating

Tags: npm, gulp, icon-fonts

My icon font files are generating just fine, but the css is not generating at all. Below is a simplified version of my gulp file, which is not working. What am I missing? I'm very new to gulp.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
iconfont = require('gulp-iconfont'),
consolidate = require('gulp-consolidate');

var fontName = 'lrcd';
gulp.task('iconfont', function(){
  gulp.src(['icons/*.svg'])
  .pipe(iconfont({ fontName: fontName }))
  .on('codepoints', function(codepoints) {
    gulp.src('icons/templates/icons.css')
    .pipe(consolidate('lodash', {
      glyphs: codepoints,
      fontName: fontName,
      fontPath: 'icons/',
      className: 'icon'
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ basename:fontName }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
  })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('icons/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['iconfont']);
```

My directories are set up as follows:

- /css
- /icons/templates/icons.css
- /icons/svg/...(contains icon svgs)

Answer (score 0):

This line is questionable: .pipe(rename({ basename:fontName })). What library is that from and where are you requiring it? Try removing that and running gulp again. Update your question with any console errors in your node console.

Comment: Removed... no luck. I'm not sure what library it was from. I copied it along with the rest of the code from some other (working) implementation of this -- one of the many examples from around the web that I've attempted to follow without success.

Answer (score 0):

Check out that your gulp-iconfont version is compatible with your templates. There were breaking compatibility changes in the last major updates ;).

Answer (score 0):

what's your gulp-iconfont version because they've changed their structures. you are using 'codepoints' but you need to use 'unicode' instead of that.